# positive fractions, denominator 4, difference equals quotient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

(4,2) are the only positive integers whose difference is equal to their quotient. Find the sum of two positive fractions, in their lowest terms, whose denominators are 4 that also share this same property.

Answer (score 2):

I prove your first sentence below:
If $x, y\in\mathbb Z$ satisfy $x-y=x/y,$ then we have :
$$x(y-1)=y^2.$$
Thus, if a prime $p$ divides $y-1,$ then $p$ divides $y$ as well, a contradiction as $y$ and $y-1$ are coprime. Hence no prime divides $y-1,$ i.e. $y=2.$ Therefore $x(2-1)=4.$

As to the second sentence, if $(x-y)/4=x/y,$ then we have:
$$x(y-4)=y^2.$$
Since any common divisor of $y$ and $y-4$ must divide $4,$ denoting $\gcd(y,y-4)=g,$ we consider three cases:
**I.** $g=1.$
We have already shown that, in this case, $y-4=1,$ i.e. $y=5$ and $x=25.$
**II.** $g=2.$
In this case $y-4$ cannot have any odd prime divisor, and $4$ cannot divide $y-4$ either, thus $y-4=2,$ i.e. $y=6$ and $x=18.$
**III.** $g=4.$
Again no common odd prime divisor of $y$ and $y-4$ can occur, while $4$ divides $y-4.$ Hence $y-4=4,$ i.e. $y=8,$ and $x=16.$
So you know all the positive fractions with the required property, and it remains to calculate the sum of two of them, which I left to you.
Hope this helps.
**Edit:**
The fractions are supposed to be in the lowest terms, thus the cases **II.** and **III.** do not count at all. Hence the only pair of fractions with the required property is $(\frac{x}{4},\frac{y}{4})=(\frac{25}{4},\frac{5}{4}),$ in which case the sum is $\frac{15}{2}.$

Comment: The fractions are supposed to have denominator 4 and to be in lowest terms, so I don't see where your cases II and III apply.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, for some reason your comment didn't notice me, so that I didn't find this out until now. And thanks for pointing it out; I shall edit it then.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac a4, \frac b4$ are the required fractions with $a, b \in \mathbb N$, then $$\frac a4 - \frac b4 = \frac ab$$

So $$\frac{4a}b = a-b$$

The right hand side is an integer, so we must have $b \mid 4a$. But by assumption, the fractions are in their lowest terms, so $b \not \mid 4$. So $b \mid a$. Let $a = kb$ with $k \in \mathbb N$.

Then $$4k = b(k-1)\\$$

By assumption, $(b,4) = 1$, so since $(k, k-1) = 1$, we have $k \mid b$.

Taking $k = 5$, we get $b = 5$, $a = 25$ with sum $30$ as one solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$ m- n = \frac{m}{n} $$ So $$ m=nk,\ nk-n=k,\ (n-1)(k-1)=1 $$

That is $$n=2,\ k=2,\ m=4 $$

Comment: Why do $m,n,k $ have to be integers here?

Comment: @Mathmo123 By hypotheses?

Comment: "Find the sum of two positive fractions, in their lowest terms, whose denominators are 4"

Comment: @Mathmo123 I think Hee Kwon Lee attemped only to prove the first claim in the question body; but this is no more than my *conjecture.*

Answer (score 0):

Let's work with $n$ instead of 4.  We achieve $a=\frac{b^2}{b-n}=b+n+\frac{n^2}{b-n}$, hence $b-n$ must divide $n^2$.  If $a/b$ must be in lowest terms, this is only possible if $b=n+1$: would $b$ be a proper divisor of $n^2$ it would contain a proper divisor $k$ of $n$. Now if $k$ is a proper divisor of $n$ it is a proper divisor of $b=n+k$ and $b/n$ would not be in lowest terms.

Thus all fractions satisfying the conditions are $\frac{n+1}{n}$ and $\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}$.